# Calling checkCurrentDictionary() from addon crashes FF - why?

Tags: firefox, crash, firefox-addon, spell-checking

I'm tyring to call the method `checkCurrentDictionary()` of `nsIEditorSpellCheck` from within an add-on. The relevant code I use is:

```
var editorSpellCheck = Cc["@mozilla.org/editor/editorspellchecker;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIEditorSpellCheck);
editorSpellCheck.checkCurrentDictionary();
```

This immediately crashes the Fx. What is going wrong here?

Comment: You never call `InitSpellChecker`, hence the crash (which shouldn't be a crash, just throwing an exception, so [I filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051173)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this probably has something to do with the fact that [`nsIEditorSpellCheck` is not a scriptable interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIEditorSpellCheck).

Basically, a [scriptable interface is one that can be used from JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Interfaces/About_Scriptable_Interfaces).

If you want to access the spell check service you can do something like:

```
let editor = editableElement.editor;
if (!editor) {
  let win = editableElement.ownerDocument.defaultView;
  editor = win.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
               getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation).
               QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
               getInterface(Ci.nsIEditingSession).
               getEditorForWindow(win);
}
if (!editor)
  throw new Error("Unable to find editor for element " + editableElement);
```

(The above is from http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/editor/AsyncSpellCheckTestHelper.jsm which is MPL).

Then you can use the [InlineSpellCheck.jsm](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/modules/InlineSpellChecker.jsm) to do some crazy stuff.

I'm not sure what you want to do though, so perhaps you should ask that more specific question as a new question.

Comment: [MDN is blatantly wrong about scriptablity](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/editor/idl/nsIEditorSpellCheck.idl#12). And the code does indeed hard-crash the whole application, because OP never called `InitSpellChecker`. Shouldn't crash anyway, so [I filed a bug about this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051173).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! Indeed it was the missing call of InitSpellChecker. I still have to deal with getting the right nsEditor-Objekt, but that's another lot.